# Glassfish not starting due to endorsed.dirs error

Tags: java, intellij-idea, glassfish-4.1

When I try to start a domain in Glassfish 4.1 from IntelliJ I'm presented with this error:

```
JVM failed to start: com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncherException: The server exited prematurely with exit code 1.
Before it died, it produced the following output:

-Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/glassfish4/glassfish/modules/endorsed:/opt/glassfish4/glassfish/lib/endorsed is not supported. Endorsed standards and standalone APIs
in modular form will be supported via the concept of upgradeable modules.
```

I found that endorsed dirs have been deprecated in Java 9, so I checked my configurations, and all seems to be using Java 8.

I also tried to start from the command line, with the same output.

Comment: The endorsed standards override mechanism was deprecated in a JDK 8 update and was removed in JDK 9. AFAIK, neither Glassfish 4.1 or 5 have been certified on JDK 9 yet. There are several issues in the Glassfish issue tracker on this topic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix -Djava.endorsed.dirs not supported, that emerged after installing WTP in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49819110/how-to-fix-djava-endorsed-dirs-not-supported-that-emerged-after-installing-wtp)

Comment: Surely it's not a duplicate of a question from 5 months after.

Answer (score 3):

I had to remove all mentions of `-Djava.endorsed.dirs` and `-Djava.ext.dirs` from my `config/domain.xml`

Comment: this is not working for me.. has anyone fixed it???