# How to fix -Djava.endorsed.dirs not supported, that emerged after installing WTP in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-wtp, endorsed

I used tomcat for projects before, but this problem came after installing the WTP, and occurs when I try to run the application on server.

First comes a message, could not create Java Virtual Machine, then in the console occures this one:

```
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\endorsed is not supported. Endorsed standards and standalone APIs
in modular form will be supported via the concept of upgradeable modules.
```

Comment: Update to the current released version.

Comment: What should I update?

Comment: WTP.   Eclipse.  If you are not running the latest Oxygen release, you need to be.

Comment: Tnx. I will do that.

Answer (score 7):

To fix this bug, you need to install/update the Eclipse Web Tools Platform (WTP) to version 3.9.4 or later.

- Select "Help > Install new Software..."
- Select or add following URL:
  http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/oxygen
- Check Web Tools Platform (WTP) 3.9.4
- Select "Next" and follow instructions

(Bug was reported to Eclipse here:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=533162)

Answer (score 4):

I've got the same error in Eclipse running Tomcat 9 on JDK 13.  I just removed the `-Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\....`  from the VM arguments then restart Tomcat again.

[image: Java VM Error]

Click on the Open Launch Configuration link from the Overview window
[image: Overview tab]

Then remove the `-Djava.endorsed` line

[image: Remove Djava line]

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse Oxygen.1a and newer releases contain changes to launch Tomcat properly with Java 9. You need to update your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue but I can resolve it by updating eclipse.
click on helps -> check for updates -> and update the eclipse to latest releases.
after update restart eclipse and check.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34598004)