# Error trying to run Tomcat [Liferay] from eclipse oxygen

Tags: java, tomcat, liferay, liferay-6, eclipse-oxygen

I'm beginning with Liferay, in fact, I'm just trying to install it and I get the following errors when I try to run the Tomcat Liferay server:

First window:

> Error: Could not create Java Virtual Machine.
>
> Error: A fatal exception has occurred Program will exit

Then when I click on `ok` I get this:

> Server Liferay v6.2 Server (Tomcat 7) at localhost failed to start.

And I get this too:

> -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\LiferayTomCat\liferay-portal-6.2.0-ce-ga1\tomcat-7.0.42\endorsed is not supported. Endorsed standards and standalone APIs
> in modular form will be supported via the concept of upgradeable modules.

I'm using windows as an OS and eclipse Oxygen April 2018 version as an IDE.
I don't know what other informations I should give.

I'm not that comfortable with all the configs, I followed the steps here https://dev.liferay.com/fr/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/6-2/developing-apps-with-liferay-ide and some other websites, if you need them I'll gladly provide them too.

Comment: Sorry, links to images of error messages are not acceptable. Please copy/paste the lines from the Tomcat log files instead.

Comment: I think this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49819110. In short, to work with Java 9 & Tomcat, you need Eclipse Oxygen with WTP 3.9.4 or later.

Answer (score 0):

If you're beginning *right now* (well, even if you're not): **Do not** start with a GA1 release from December 2013. There's no need to run into issues that have long been fixed, either in that version or in future versions.

Either go with the latest available major release (7.1, as of a few weeks ago, recommended) or at least with the latest update of the major release you need to use. If, for some reason, you *must* be on 6.2, use 6.2.5 GA6, released in November 2017 (note that there won't be any more updates to it). With 7.0, the whole architecture changed dramatically to utilize OSGi, and you should rather start to learn on the future architecture, and not on the legacy concepts.

That being said, especially as you're just beginning: I'd also recommend to go with the tools matching your release. You're linking to the Liferay IDE installation that says "supports Eclipse 4.2.x or greater", and in order to work around changed defaults in future versions, I'd actually try with the referenced tools (or download the referenced full version of Liferay IDE to get experience, then upgrade the toolchain when you're familiar with the environment)

One more word about the versions: Liferay, as an enterprise product/project, runs on various environments that impose a limit on the supported Java versions. If you look at the [compatibility list](https://web.liferay.com/services/support/compatibility-matrix) for the enterprise supported versions, you'll find out that even the latest version isn't supported on Java 9 (due to several of the enterprise appservers not supporting this language level). You're safest (again, especially in the beginning) to limit yourself to the versions listed there.

And note again that the exact version you're listing was released in 2013. Back then, Java 7 was current, Java8 wasn't released yet. Java8 is listed in the compatibility list today, but wasn't supported with the initial release.