# Could not create Java virtual machine and it says that endorsed is not supported

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat9

> -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Apache\apache-tomcat-9.0.37\endorsed is not supported. Endorsed standards and standalone APIs in modular form will
> be supported via the concept of upgradeable modules.

Comment: Use an older JDK for now.

Comment: Do you get this when running Tomcat itself, or do you get this when launching Tomcat from something else (eg Eclipse)? In that case, it might be a duplicate of [How to fix -Djava.endorsed.dirs not supported, that emerged after installing WTP in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49819110/how-to-fix-djava-endorsed-dirs-not-supported-that-emerged-after-installing-wtp)

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same problem.  To resolve it, just remove the line "-Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:..." from the Tomcat9 Properties in "Java Options" under Java Tab then
restart tomcat
[image: Remove the -Djava.endorsed line]

Steps to fix it follows:

```
-Open Tomcat9.exe from the tomcat lib folder
-From the Tomcat9 Properties screen, select the Java Tab
-Remove the line "-Djava.endorsed.dirs=..." then
-Select the General Tab and click on the Start button to Restart Tomcat
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can go to open run configuration -> click tomcat server -> click arguments

Under Vm arguments section remover -Djava.endrosed.dirs property